# Reference Lookup Table from Inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, lookup

I have a lookup table and I want to be able to use it within a Javascript function. For my purposes, I'm using the DT package within R, but I'm stuck on the JS.

Specifically, for each table data (in the 1st column), I want to use Javascript to assign a 'table' attribute based on the lookup table.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output) {

  speedLKU <- data.frame(Num = c('4','7','8'), Desc = c('Low','Medium','High'))

  output$carTable <- renderDataTable({

    cars[1:5,] %>% datatable(
      rownames = FALSE
    )

  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput('carTable'))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So the cells (1,1) and (2,1) should have a 'title' attribute of 'Low'. Cells (3,1) and (4,1) should have a 'title' attribute of 'Medium'. And cell (5,1) should have a 'title' attribute of 'High'.

Comment: I suppose I could merge the lookup table with the dataset, reference the necessary column using JS, then hide the column using columnDefs in DT.

Comment: where is that `JS` function? Please share

Comment: Within my `datatable()` call, these are the options:
`options = list(
        rowCallback = JS(
          "function(row, data) {",
          "$('td:eq(12)', row).attr('title', data[20]);",
          "}"),
        columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 20))`

Comment: Yeah I know, but where is your attempt of using it?